# Can´t connect to my mongoDB docker with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have a mongoDB docker running locally, which is called "some-mongo". On the same computer I also have running my back-end server (Made with nodeJS). The problem is connecting my nodeJS server to the local mongo docker using the "mongoose" module.

I have launched my mongoDB docker by running the following command:

```sh
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

And my nodeJS server tries to connect to the mongo docker as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
//Connect to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://local-host:27017/some-mongo')
  .then(db => console.log('DB Mongo: connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```sh
Server on port 3000
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [local-host:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND local-host local-host:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/bisite/Documents/Git/Trusted-Industry/TrustedIndustryFront/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at connect (/Users/bisite/Documents/Git/Trusted-Industry/TrustedIndustryFront/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:580:14)
    at makeConnection (/Users/bisite/Documents/Git/Trusted-Industry/TrustedIndustryFront/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/Users/bisite/Documents/Git/Trusted-Industry/TrustedIndustryFront/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/Users/bisite/Documents/Git/Trusted-Industry/TrustedIndustryFront/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Whether mongo is running???

Comment: It is running locally in a docker container

Comment: local-host ? or localhost ?

Comment: it should be `localhost` not `local-host`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in a single Docker Container you'd have to expose the port `27017` like this:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo -p 27017:27107
```

But it would be a much safer approach to use `docker-compose` with both, mongoDB and app, as containerized applications.
This way you don't have to expose the mongo port outside your docker infrastructure.